# SQL sum over a time interval / rows

Tags: sql, postgresql, sum

the following code

```
SELECT distinct DATE_PART('year',date) as year_date,
DATE_PART('month',date) as month_date,
count(prepare_first_buyer.person_id) as no_of_customers_month
FROM
(
SELECT DATE(bestelldatum)  ,person_id
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY person_id)
FROM ani.bestellung
) prepare_first_buyer
WHERE row_number=1
GROUP BY DATE_PART('year',date),DATE_PART('month',date)
ORDER BY DATE_PART('year',date),DATE_PART('month',date)
```

gives this table back:

```
| year_date | month_date | no_of_customers_month |
|:--------- |:----------:| ---------------------:|
| 2017      | 1          | 2                     |
| 2017      | 2          | 5                     |
| 2017      | 3          | 4                     |
| 2017      | 4          | 8                     |
| 2017      | 5          | 1                     |
| .         | .          | .                     |
| .         | .          | .                     |
```

where als three are numeric values.
I need now a new column were i sum up all values from 'no_of_customers_month' for 12 months back.
e.g.

```
| year_date | month_date | no_of_customers_month | sum_12mon |
|:--------- |:----------:| :--------------------:|----------:|
| 2019      | 1          | 2                     |    23     |
```

where 23 is the sum from 2019-1 back to 2018-1 over 'no_of_customers_month'.

Thx for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', date) as yyyymm,
       COUNT(*) as no_of_customers_month,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', date) RANGE BETWEEN '11 month' PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM (SELECT DATE(bestelldatum), person_id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY person_id)
      FROM ani.bestellung
     ) b
WHERE row_number = 1
GROUP BY yyyymm
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```

Note:  This uses `date_trunc()` to retrieve the year/month as a *date*, allowing the use of `range()`.  I also find a date more convenient than having the year and month in separate columns.

Some versions of Postgres don't support `range` window frames.  Assuming you have data for each month, you can use `rows`:

```
SELECT DATE_TRUNC('month', date) as yyyymm,
       COUNT(*) as no_of_customers_month,
       SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER (ORDER BY DATE_TRUNC('month', date) ROWS BETWEEN 11 PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW)
FROM (SELECT DATE(bestelldatum), person_id,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY person_id ORDER BY person_id)
      FROM ani.bestellung
     ) b
WHERE row_number = 1
GROUP BY yyyymm
ORDER BY yyyymm;
```